# Не удается получить login и pass из запроса

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть метод Api-контроллера:

```
public async Task<ApiResult> CreateOrChange([System.Web.Mvc.Bind(Include = "id,login,pass")] jsonObject jObj)
    {
       //то что содержит jObj:
       //jObj.id == 100;
       //jObj.login == null;
       //jObj.pass == null;
    }
```

Id из запроса подцепляется, а вот login и pass равны null. В чем проблема? При чем аналогичный метод в Web Controller'е работает исправно и передает в объект логин и пасс.

Код класса jsonObject:

```
public class jsonObject
{    
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }   
}
```

Запрос:
POST http://localhost:12345/api/myController/CreateOrChange
В теле запроса JSON:

```
{
  "id": 100,
  "login": "SomeLogin",
  "pass": "SomePass"
}
```

Content-Type указан соответствующий.

Comment: По тому маленькому кусочку кода, что вы привели, непонятно абсолютно ничего. [Ознакомьтесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и попробуйте отредактировать ваш вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167, даже никаких идей? Сейчас выложу код объекта, не понимаю только, зачем.

Comment: Я думаю очень поможет, если вы выложите [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , включая не только контроллер, но и сам запрос, что вы отправляете в этот контроллер.

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил пример запроса.

Comment: Вы даете нам объекты, но не как не то, что под "капотом". Это тоже самое, что сказать "У меня не едет машина. Жигули, цвет синий.". Вот попробуйте теперь понять, почему она не "едет". Задавайте вопросы так, что бы их могло понять как можно больше людей, описывая каждую мелочь, которая касается вопроса, предоставляйте как можно больше данных, кода и др. информацию!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я не понимаю, что именно вам дать. Скажите какой код вам нужен - я скину. Я не могу дать проект целиком, как и не видоизмененный код. У меня нету ни одной идеи, по этому без понятия что вам скидывать.

Comment: Может быть мне следует указать строку подключения к БД? Как думаете? Это поможет?

Comment: Или скинуть код какой-нибудь библиотеки из подключенных к проекту?

Comment: Кроме идеи что проблема связанна с системой авторизации и login/pass съедаются чем-то. Но чем?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, по вашему примеру. Я бы уточнил, не едет или не заводится? А проверьте зажигание. А посмотрите туда. Я без понятия какой кусок из всего кода вам скинуть, потому что не имею понятия о возможных причинах проблемы.